# VS code is not printing first element of array in debug console

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

VS code is not printing first element of array in debug console.

```
[New Thread 19288.0x27cc]
sorted array:
  1  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  =thread-exited,id="1",group-id="i1"
```

However, if I run the same program using terminal with gcc in vscode- it displays all the elements -

```
sorted array:
0  1  1  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
```

It is always missing the first element. Also, how can I get the output in the windows command shell if I do not want it in the debug console of VS code.

```
void printlist(int *arr, int size)
{
    printf("sorted array: \n");
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        printf("%d  ", arr[i]);
}   
int main(void)
    {
        //int arr[] = {4,1,3,6,9,0,2,1};
        int arr[] = {7,2,1,6,8,5,0,1,1,3,4};
        int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
        int start=0, end=size-1;
        quicksort(arr, start, end);
        printlist(arr, size);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: [MCVE] please. My bet is on some uninitialized variable...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Have provide the code snippet. I dont think it is due to unitialized variable coz array is defined statically.

Comment: The implementation of `quicksort` is missing. But yeah, I withdraw my bet as it could be some other UB.

Comment: You've not shown the `quicksort()` function, and it could be UB (undefined behaviour) in the sorting function that leads to different results on different compilers.  It would be a good idea to add a newline at the end of the printed list.

Comment: May be something is wrong in quicksort(). So just for debugging it yourself, comment the call to quicksort() and print the unsorted array using printlist(). Does it get printed properly?

Comment: I do note that the erroneous output has a couple of leading blanks on the second line which should follow a number — which is a bit peculiar.

Comment: @MayurK Tried that. It doesn not print 7.
sorted array:
  2  1  6  8  5  0  1  1  3  4  =thread-exited,id="1",group-id="i1"

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah. If I give '\n' this works correctly and prints all elements however, space "  " or tab (\t) does not give and omit the first element. It's strange.
Also can you please let me know how can I get the output in the windows prompt if I run code in VScode (ctrl+F5).

Comment: One more question. Are you getting any warning from compiler? You can initialize int i = 0; before for loop and try once. Also, pint arr address and size value in calling and called functions. It might give some hint.

Comment: @MayurK No warnings/errors. I've "-Werror" compiler flag enabled while building. As Jonathan mentioned, if I give printf("%d\n", arr[i]); things works perfectly. But not sure why space or a tab (\t) does not work and always omit the first element. However, it works if in the same IDE if I compile using gcc in the terminal.

Comment: I have never used VSCode so I can't help with how to run code within it.

Comment: You still haven't provided [mcve] and your question is about to get closed. If you want to get an answer and not speculation you better improve it before that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Quicksort() implementation is not even required to be shared. As said above in the comment, it is seen even when the call to quicksort() is commented out. I do not understand what else piece of code you're looking for from me.